# I have a problem with my Discord bot (Minecraft server status bot)

Tags: node.js, discord.js

This is the `index.js` script of the bot:

```js
const { Client, RichEmbed } = require('discord.js')

const bot = new Client()

const util = require('minecraft-server-util')

const token = 'bot_token'

const PREFIX = 'l.'

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot has come online.')
})

bot.on('message', message => {

    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(' ')

    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'status':

            util.status('IP', (PORT), (error, reponse) => {
                if (error) throw error
                const Embed = new RichEmbed()
                    .setTitle('Server Status')
                    .addField('Server IP', reponse.host)
                    .addField('Server Version', reponse.version)
                    .addField('Online Players', reponse.onlinePlayers)
                    .addField('Max Players', reponse.maxPlayers)

                message.channel.send(Embed)
            })
            break

    }

})

bot.login(token)
```

When I type `node .` in the console and I type `l.status` on the Discord server, it shows this error on the console:

```
(node:3300) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Expected 'options' to
be an object or undefined, got number
    at C:\Users\HNRK\Desktop\LightSide\node_modules\minecraft-server-util\dist\status.js:46:25
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\HNRK\Desktop\LightSide\node_modules\minecraft-server-util\dist\status.js:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\Users\HNRK\Desktop\LightSide\node_modules\minecraft-server-util\dist\status.js:4:12)
    at status (C:\Users\HNRK\Desktop\LightSide\node_modules\minecraft-server-util\dist\status.js:40:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HNRK\Desktop\LightSide\node_modules\minecraft-server-util\dist\status.js:113:17)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\HNRK\Desktop\LightSide\node_modules\minecraft-server-util\dist\status.js:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:3300) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the
CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:3300) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Can anybody help? I also tried a lot of different solutions, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an outdatet version of discord.js. Type `npm i discord.js@latest` into your terminal. In the latest version of discord.js, `RichEmbed()` has been removed and replaced by `MessageEmbed()`.

Comment: This also doenst work it doesnt send any message or embed on the discord server and it doesnt show any error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer based on assumption since I've never used `minecraft-server-util` before. Also assuming that you're using the latest `minecraft-server-util`,

Based on the error;

> Expected 'options' to be an object or undefined, got number

And, based on  [this commit](https://github.com/PassTheMayo/minecraft-server-util/blob/c482d20a6e940fabc2617b2eb1111dacb0c3db93/src/model/Options.ts#L1), You should pass the **2nd argument** as an **object** instead of `PORT` since it's a type of [StatusOptions](https://github.com/PassTheMayo/minecraft-server-util/blob/c482d20a6e940fabc2617b2eb1111dacb0c3db93/src/model/Options.ts#L6) instead of a `number`.

So, instead of;

```
util.status('IP', (PORT), (error, reponse) => {
```

You should be doing;

```
util.status('IP', {
  port: (PORT)
}, (error, reponse) => {
```

Comment: This doesnt work it doesnt send any messages in discord and it doesnt show any errors in the console but thx for your effort tho.